# Why am I getting inconsistent results when attempting to update my instance group using `gcloud`?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I have an instance group in GCP, and I am working on automating the deployment process. The instances in this group are based on a tagged GCR image. When a new image is pushed to the container registry, we have been manually triggering an upgrade by navigating to the instance group from console.cloud.google.com, clicking "restart/replace vms", and setting these options:

- Operation: replace
- Maximum surge: 3
- Maximum unavailable: 0

Here is my `gcloud` command for doing the same thing ([link to Google's documentation about this command](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups)):

```
gcloud beta compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update my-instance-group \
    --version=template=my-template-with-image \
    --replacement-method=substitute \
    --max-surge=3 \
    --max-unavailable=0 \
    --region=us-central1
```

Manually, the process always works. But the `gcloud` command is flaky. It always appears to succeed from the command line, but the instance groups are not always restarted. I have even tried adding these two flags, and the restart attempt was still unreliable:

```
    --minimal-action=replace \
    --most-disruptive-allowed-action=replace \
```

There is quite a lot of output from the `gcloud` command (which I can provide, if necessary), but here are the only parts of the output that differ between a successful and unsuccessful attempt:

Good:

```
currentActions:
  creating: 1
status:
  isStable: false
  versionTarget:
    isReached: false
```

Bad:

```
currentActions:
  creating: 0
status:
  isStable: true
  versionTarget:
    isReached: true
```

That is pretty much the extent of my knowledge at this point. I am not sure how to move forward in automating the build process, and I have been unable to find answers from the documentation so far.

I hope I was not too verbose, and thank you in advance to anyone who spends time on this :)

Comment: 1) What changes are you making to the instance template? 2) Describe your configuration. 3) Describe the configuration after start-update. 4) Your statement **but the instance groups are not always restarted** does not clearly define what problem you are experiencing. 5) Do not use **beta** commands when the GA version is available unless you have a specific reason. 6) For your use case (container image update) I use **replace** instead of **start-update**.

Comment: @JohnHanley


**1)** The instance template is the same. It is based on the same image, but I perform this replacement action when there is an updated image

**2)** We have an https load balancer with three instance groups as backends (one in asia pacific, one in europe west, and one in us central). All a "deploy" entails for us is replacing the VMs in each instance group with new VMs based on the most recent image from GCR

Comment: Part 2
**3)** The configuration after start-update is essentially the same - the only difference is that the VMs in the instance group at the end are using a newer image
**4)** When I say "the instance groups are not always restarted", what I mean is that I run the command, then check the instance group on the Google cloud console. I can easily see whether new instances are being created, and the creation time of any active instances. "the instance groups are not always restarted" simply means I ran the command, but new instances were not created and the old instances were not removed

Comment: Final part **5)** My reason for using a `beta` command was that I could not find an alternative to do the same operation that was not in beta
**6)** Thank you! I tried using `replace` instead of `start-update`, and that seemed to work for the three instance groups. Time will tell whether it works consistently, or if I will observe similar inconsistent behavior

Thank you for your detailed response, and I hope I responded to all your points sufficiently. I am happy to clarify anything if that would help, and I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Actions like replacing instances will have two entries in logging. One for the start action and one for the completion. The logs will have errors if any.